# Limit Android Service Binding

Tags: android, security, android-service, android-permissions, android-service-binding

IS there any approach allows the android service only accept the binding from specific components **(NOT APP)** which could be the components of partner's APP or in-house APP.

Using permission doesn't satisfy my situation, because any APP declared using this permission will be able to bind my service. What I want to do is opposite that it's me who chooses which components can bind with my service.

Comment: if you are using `AIDL` then override `Stub#onTransact` and do your checks there

Comment: AIDL. I'm checking with onTransact now. It seems good for me

Comment: ``Stub#onTransact`` is good. My final solution is using ``Binder#getCallingUid`` in this function to identifier the caller. Thanks